# ExtendedAttribute Elements in XML

Tags: python, xml

[PYTHON]
I am having a XML which has an extended attribute which is 'customfields', data type = a dictionary. I don't know how to interpret the content inside the extended attribute correctly?
Is it considered as a column in the table? When I try to extract the text, it returns None as the result. Please help!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lCp3X1LxcD6gUKJbGxiaUvWQNVSKubJQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) for parsing complex xml files

Comment: Please post a sample (not all if very large) of XML in body of post and not as a link that will go dead for future readers. Be sure to include root node since it may carry relevant info like namespaces. Also, clearly point to section you are referring to whether it is an attribute or element.

Comment: "When I try to extract the text, it returns None...". Please show us your code. Also note that "attribute" has a very specific meaning in XML.

Comment: Thanks guys & special thanks to Codelt ! xmltodict works better for me. Solved.